# Import data with each value containing column labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

I have data in a text file with no headers. The values in each row have a label indicating which column they belong to. I want to take those labels as column names and feed the data under the columns.

I want to import a text file containing this:

```
Column1=variable11&Column2=variable12&Column3=variable13&Column4=variable14
Column1=variable12&Column2=variable22&Column3=variable23
Column1=variable13&Column2=variable32&Column3=variable33&Column4=variable34&Column5=variable35
```

I expect the result to be a table like this:

```
Column1         Column2         Column3         Column4         Column5
variable11  variable12  variable13  variable14  
variable21  variable22  variable23      
variable31  variable32  variable33  variable34  variable35
```

Comment: Is this `Column1=variable1=21` on row 2 correct?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that `Column1=variable1=21` on line 2 and 3 are mistakes.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', header=None)

df = df[0].str.split('=|&', expand=True)
tmp = df.loc[:,1::2].copy()
tmp.columns = df.loc[:,::2].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0])
```

output

```
    Column1     Column2     Column3     column4     Column5
0   variable11  variable12  variable13  variable14  None
1   variable21  variable22  variable23  None        None
2   variable31  variable32  variable33  variable34  variable35
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple typo in your data, you may need `split` twice to get the format back to `dict` , then pass the `dict` to `pandas.DataFrame` constructor

```
pd.DataFrame([dict(x)for x in df.Read.str.split('&').apply(lambda x : [tuple(y.split('=',1)) for y in x])])
Out[128]: 
        Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5     column4
0    variable11  variable12  variable13         NaN         NaN  variable14
1  variable1=21  variable22  variable23         NaN         NaN         NaN
2  variable1=31  variable32  variable33  variable34  variable35         NaN

df=pd.DataFrame([dict(x)for x in df.Read.str.split('&').apply(lambda x : [tuple(y.split('=',1)) for y in x])])
df.columns=df.columns.str.upper()
df=df.sum(axis=1,level=0)
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the repeatition of column names?